# Selectin a specific row based on an attribute of another table

Tags: sql

I'm in need to display a specific result out of an attribute.
So, for example, let's take two tables and join them together, in a relation one to many. If you have an attribute in the first table that says '7' how do you display the 7th result of the second one?

A situation like that:

[image: two tables]

Imagine to add an attribute to the first table that says '3'. How can you display the 3rd results of the second for the same emp_id?

Can you please lend me some help? I'm trying to figure out what to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` like this:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON b.EMP_ID = a.EMP_ID
OFFSET 3 ROWS --Here place n rows to skip
LIMIT 1 ROW ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

select t2.sal_det
from table2 as t2, table1 as t1
where t1.sal=t2.sal_det